# Get geometry of text on an image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'd like to draw a text onto an image in a way like this:

```
convert -quality 100 -font Oswald-Regular -pointsize 515 -fill black -draw "text 1339.0,1099 'some text'" /tmp/ascript.png /tmp/ascript.png
```

and I need to know the dimensions of the text with the above parameters (size, font, text). How can I get that?

I tried something like this:

```
convert -size 5000x1500 xc:lightblue -font Oswald-Regular -pointsize 515 -fill none -undercolor white -annotate +20+100 'some text' -trim  info:
```

but it's giving false result:

```
xc:lightblue XC 1834x250 5000x1500+19+0 16-bit sRGB 0.010u 0:00.000
```

.

What is the proper way (or a working way) to get the dimension of a drawn image based on this 3 parameters (font, size, text)?

I'm not strictly binded to ImageMagick, it can be any command line tool for the Linux shell, however, the text will be drawn by convert.

Comment: I don't mind how ineffective the solution is, i mean it can take up to 10 seconds to process for a 3 words long text... . I don't mind.

Comment: Try to avoid using `-quality` on PNG images. It doesn't work anything like for JPEGs, and PNG images are already lossless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple simple ways to get the dimensions using ImageMagick with commands like this...

```
convert -size 5000x1500 xc:lightblue -font Oswald-Regular -pointsize 515 \
    -fill none -undercolor white -annotate +20+100 'some text' \
    -format "%[@]\n" info:
```

That uses the FX escape "%@" as the formatting string for the "info:" output. It will show IM's calculation of the after-trim width, height, horizontal offset, and vertical offset like "WxH+X+Y".

This similar command just gives the width and height of the trimmed text...

```
convert -size 5000x1500 xc:lightblue -font Oswald-Regular -pointsize 515 \
    -fill none -undercolor white -annotate +20+100 'some text' \
    -trim +repage -format "%[w]x%[h]\n" info:
```

That will trim the text, reset the paging geometry with "+repage", then output a string showing "WxH".

––– Edited to Add –––

I tried your image [with_text.png](http://87.229.108.143/files/stack_question_23THj/files/with_text.png) with these commands. The output immediately follows each command...

```
convert with_text.png -format "%[@]\n" info:
1807x389+512+115

convert with_text.png -trim +repage -format "%[w]x%[h]\n" info:
1807x389
```

Those were tested with IMv6.8.9-9 on ubuntu bash on Windows 10. If you use that actual image and those commands, I'm not sure why you would get different results.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me. Using both commands from You resulting 1834x250. So the height is 250, however if I use the first command from _my_ post and I open the file (for instance with gimp) I can see that the height is around 380px. Same font, same pointsize, same text. Can You tell me what do I do wrongly? Or where is the difference coming from?

Comment: testing this: convert -size 5000x1500 xc:white -font Oswald-Regular -pointsize 515     -fill none -undercolor white -annotate +1000+1000 'some text'     -format "%[@]\n" info:

Comment: First you should restructure your command more like this... `convert <input> <do stuff> <output>`, although that shouldn't cause the difference you describe. It would be helpful if you can post some examples of your output before and after the trim.

Comment: I've put my examples here: http://87.229.108.143/files/stack_question_23THj/ . (No space and image upload possibility in the comments). My ImageMagick version is: 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 .

Comment: I tested your image. See the "edited-to-add" part at the end of my original post.

Comment: The new way works. I don't mind, but it means at first I need to create the image with the text, and I need to make the trim on it. Well, interesting why do I still get 250 result for the first commands. Maybe is there any limitation there? It'd be silly.

Comment: It will work exactly the same way if you read in the image, as I did in the examples above, or if you create the image with label or annotate before checking its dimensions.